# Including graph images in an email sent from Application

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-plot

I'm using Core Plot for charting in my app. One of the use scenarios for the app requires me to implement sending emails with the charts - from the default email client.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to implement it - as in a single email there could be as many as 40 charts included... I could render the chart, then use the contents of its view as CoreGraphics context and, I guess, generate CGImage and UIImage from there, then somehow include it in an email... but I'm wondering if there isn't a simpler way to achieve it?

One option would be, of course, to use Core Plot for the in-app plotting, and in the email use some online library for the plots - like Google Charts (so, instead of having the images attached or inline in the mail, I could just use `<img src="..." />` instead - but I'm not sure if it's what I should really do (I don't want to use Google Chart entirely for my charting, as the app should be usable without internet access)...

What would be the best way to generate the charts for sending in an email?

(Or maybe there's a better way to send it? Something like generating a PDF report with graphs inside?)

Comment: If you've rendered the chart, don't you already have an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have Core Plot graphs set up, just use `[graph imageOfLayer]` to get a `UIImage` of the graph. You can use this to create an image for the email or draw into a PDF context. You can also export the graph to PDF directly by using `[graph dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer]`.